# Admob Impression, How to

Tags: android, admob

I'm about to integrate Admob in my app and I know this isn't a "coding error question" but I need some clarification on Admob from someone that use it.

I'd like to know how Impressions work and calculate it.

**They just count 1 impression when the Ad appear? So If I keep that Ad only for some seconds or 60 seconds is the same thing? Sound strange to me.**

More fair seem to me that Impressions are calculated with the seconds that they were shown...

Someone can explain to me How the thing work?

Answer (score 0):

Impressions are a count of the number of times an ad is shown to a user, regardless of the duration it is displayed.

Comment: So If I put 1 Ad in an Activity that the user see for only 2 seconds count as 1? Sound strange

Comment: That's pretty much it. It's used to track the number of ads shown to a user versus the number of ads requested from the server. It's not just an AdMob term either, it's universal.

Comment: But so they pay for Impression or Click? I thought the pay for Impression

Comment: It depends on the bid type. Some ads are CPC which are paid based on the number of clicks. Others are paid based on the number of impressions (usually per 1000 impressions).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience ad is rotated after some time -  giving you more impressions

Answer (score 0):

When talking about interstitial ad, an impression is counted every time the user see it regardless of the time it being presented

Banners are different, on the admob dashboard you can define refresh intervals when the default is 60 seconds, which mean that every 60 seconds a new banner will be called and when shown it is counted as impression

[banner refresh](http://prntscr.com/dvxewv)